# How to take over props to other components? TypeScript React

Tags: reactjs

I have a problem with react.
How Should I take props over other components?
I would like to use the Other function component...

```
         export const MainComponent = (props: ImportantProps): JSX.Element => {
         return (
             <OtherComponent {...this.props} />
          );
          export default function OtherComponent(props: ImportantProps) {
          ///
          }
```

Comment: It is a function component, remove the this should make it work